# Draw Line between 2 buttons in java gui swift , it worked but its not accurate

Tags: java, swing

I have this simple code:

```
class Success extends JFrame {

    public JButton button1;
    public JButton button2;

    public Success() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(600, 800);

        button1 = new JButton("press");
        button2 = new JButton("this");
        button1.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 100);
        button2.setBounds(400, 500, 100, 100);

        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.setLayout(null);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);  
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawLine(button1.getX(), button1.getY(), button2.getX(), button2.getY());
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Success s = new Success();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

it works but checkout this image:

[image]

I want the accurate position of buttons.

I tried `getLocationOnScreen()` and `getLocation()` but they had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should never override the `paint` method of a `JFrame`, but rather the `paintComponent` method of your content panel.

That being said, [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Component)) has methods to find the coordinates, given the source (the button in your case) and the destination (the frame in your case) `Component` objects :

```
public void paint(final Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Point p1 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(button1, 0, 0, this);
        Point p2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(button2, 0, 0, this);

        g2.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    }
```

Note that you probably encountered the problem of the frame's title bar/border not being taken into account, hence the vertical shift .

Comment: And not to forget to get rid of the null layout and use a [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead